# Phrase for a useful or comforting illusion

Tags: phrase-requests, euphemisms

Looking for an expression or a phrase for a comforting or useful illusion or simulacrum. Something that is widely held, yet seldom scrutinized. Something so common it defies scrutiny. Something workable, but based on a premise with minor flaws that impede progress. A concept, that when vocalized, would have us nodding our heads. Perhaps useful because of it provides a quick or easy perspective which is successful.

Comment: "based on a premise with minor flaws that impede progress" wouldn't these flaws invite scrutiny?

Comment: Excellent observation which stabs to the heart of the matter. Widespread acceptance seems to have anesthetized the community.

Comment: *Myth* would seem to check all those boxes nicely, but it has additional criteria (as *sacred story)* that may disqualify whatever thing you hope to apply this word to.

Comment: Please give us a sample sentence with a blank space  _______ where the word would go.  For example I could guess **platitude** or **fool's paradise**, but without a sentence to put it in, I don't know if it would fit. There are loads of possibilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a word or phrase for a false belief or opinion on something people hold true and repeat because they have heard it repeated so many times?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297877/what-is-another-word-for-a-false-belief-or-opinion-on-something-that-people-hold)

Comment: Is the focus here that the belief is commonly held and unquestioned, or that it is comforting / useful but known to be an illusion? Both? The proposed duplicate only covers the first.

Answer (score 1):

A **security blanket**, as used by Linus in the Peanuts comic strip. All of the Peanuts characters are “positive”, so the term is more whimsical than hurtful.

https://peanuts.fandom.com/wiki/Linus%27_security_blanket

This term could be used in a context like the following:

“Let’s start out with X as a kind of security blanket...”.

Answer (score 0):

***aphorism***

> a short clever saying that is intended to express a general truth

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aphorism)

Answer (score -1):

Additional to Cascabel’s answer:

[Proverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proverb) a brief popular epigram.

[Adage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adage) a saying, often in metaphorical form, that typically embodies a common observation.

[Saw](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saw) - Maxim or proverb.

Etc....

All of these convey a sense of “universal truth” but are often at their core little more than hot air.

For example:  You break up with a significant other and someone tells you:

> It’s better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all.

On the surface, this sounds like a universally true statement.  Yet, as it does nothing to salve the pain you’re feeling, its “universal truth” is suspect.

Answer (score -1):

***façon de parler*** (n.)

> A turn of phrase or rhetorical formula, especially one that ought not
> to be taken literally, but rather as employed for convenience of
> expression only. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fa%C3%A7on_de_parler)

> A way or manner of speaking; a mere phrase or formula.
>
> S. H. Hodgson *Let*. 8 Apr. in R. B. Perry Thought & Char. W. James
> (1935) I. 642   What is ‘the mind’?.. I suspect it is a mere ***façon
> de parler***..which has a basis neither in psychological construction
> nor in philosophical analysis.
>
> 1907   W. De Morgan *Alice-for-Short* xlii. 439   Which was palpably a
> lie, taken literally; but was a ***façon-de-parler*** that passed muster,
> taken leniently. OED

---

> Leibniz was well aware of the problems that this raised. His reaction
> was to urge us not to take talk of infinitesimal quantities literally.
> We could think of it as just a ***façon de parler***, or as a
> '**useful fiction**', to be justified by appeal to its enormous
> **utility**. [A. W. Moore; *The Infinite*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Infinite/ADdyDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=facon%20de%20parler%20useful&pg=PT93&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> Let us distinguish in mental phenomena a *virtual* part implemented by
> neurophysiological processes and a *fictitious* part not implemented at
> all, that is an **illusion** (or an idealization, or a mere ***façon de
> parler***) whose introduction in our language sometimes may be **quite
> useful** but that strictly speaking **does not exist**. [Oscar Vilarroya
> et al.; *Social Brain Matters*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Social_Brain_Matters/pzWonWxlWDAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Let%20us%20distinguish%20in%20mental%20phenomena%20a%20virtual%20part%20implemented%20by%20neurophysiological%20processes%22&pg=PA184&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> There are no discrete unities identical to themselves and different
> from others. Distinguishing between natural kinds is merely ***façon
> de parler***, referring only to a certain way of *perceiving* reality.
> [Robert Spaemann; *Essays in Anthropology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Essays_in_Anthropology/coNJAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facon%20de%20parler%22%20illusion&pg=PT44&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> On the other hand, I do not know of any significant study of
> postmodernism that sees it object as a "reality" that is out there, to
> be discovered and mapped. What may appear as a result of the mimetic
> illusion is almost always a mere ***façon de
> parler***, which is based on certain mimetic metaphors (the mind as a mirror, the mirror of nature, etc.) built into our language. [M.
> Calinescu in M. Calinescu and D. Fokkema (eds.); *Exploring
> Postmodernism*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Exploring_Postmodernism/Pl4siiSXKi4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=What%20is%20a%20%22facon%20de%20parler%22%20%20illusion&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover) (1987)

> When he says " paranoid streak", he does not really mean the term"
> paranoid" to be taken seriously—it is just a ***facon de parler***.
> [Stephen Toulmin; *The Return to Cosmology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Return_to_Cosmology/dA5fG8mTAB8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facon%20de%20parler%22&pg=PA189&printsec=frontcover) (1985)